# d3.js - shading effect doesn't work fine in google chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shadow

I am not an expert level coder in d3.js. I have created a graph that uses colored arc inside the circle based on the data.

I have applied shading effect to the arcs, it works fine with FireFix but it shows the shaded area for the path (arc) outside the arc too.

```
var data = [
    {name: "A", val: 11975},  
    {name: "B", val: 5871}, 
    {name: "C", val: 8916}
];

var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
    labelr = r + 30, // radius for label anchor
    color = d3.scale.category20(),
    donut = d3.layout.pie(),
    arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(r * .6).outerRadius(r);

var vis = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w + 150)
    .attr("height", h);

// filters go in defs element
    var defs = vis.append("defs");

    // create filter with id #drop-shadow
    // height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
    var filter = defs.append("filter")
        .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
        .attr("height", "150%");

    // SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
    // convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
    // in blur
    filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
        .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
        .attr("stdDeviation", 3)
        .attr("result", "blur");

    // translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
    // store result in offsetBlur
    var feOffset = filter.append("feOffset")
        .attr("in", "blur")
        .attr("dx", 3)
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

    // overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
    // feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
    var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

    feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
    feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
        .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(donut.value(function(d) { return d.val }))
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (r + 30) + "," + r + ")");

arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc)
.style("filter", function (d,i){ return "url(#drop-shadow)" ; });

arcs.append("svg:text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var c = arc.centroid(d),
            x = c[0],
            y = c[1],
            // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
            h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
        return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
           (y/h * labelr) +  ")"; 
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")

    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
        // are we past the center?
        return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle)/2 > Math.PI ?
            "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d, i) { return d.value.toFixed(2); });
```

I have edited a fiddle, here's the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/GQDUS/368/

You can see the difference in FF and google chrome easily. Please help me out with this.

Comment: I can't see any difference, maybe post an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you don't have the latest browser version that doesn't support d3 filter property that well